# Dynamic Windows Form Initialization

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to write a program (*console initialized*) in C# that dynamically initializes a set of windows forms.

It's a tournament program that allows the user to manage multiple stations at once.

So, the best I've come up with is something like, say, the user wants to manage three stations.

```
TournamentForm[] T = new TournamentForm[3];

void startTournament()
{
    for (int count = 0; count < t.length; count++)
    {
        T[count] = new TournamentForm();
        T[count].show();
    }
}
```

The inherent problem with this approach is that at the end of each loop, the form is closed.

Is there a means of dynamically initializing windows forms, or do I have to long code a maximum number of windows instances?

---

Hmm... I may have had an idea using recursion while writing this. Still posting the question in case there's a better answer.

---

So I have been using this forum as a thought board... Shoot me. I prefer holes shot in my ideas early on.

@Bas here is code that compiles

```
namespace Tournament_2._1
{
    class Program
    {
        static MainWindow[] test = new MainWindow[2];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartTournament();
        }

        private static void StartTournament()
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < test.Length; count++)
            {
                test[count] = new MainWindow();

                test[count].Show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What I was missing while the for loop was in the Main() method (even while stepping through each line) was that the windows were being closed at the end of the Main() method, not at the end of each loop.

To try to manage this I have tried a couple ways of pausing the console, and none have been allowing focus on the forms.

Same problem, different location.

Comment: Do you want a constructor?

Comment: The forms shouldn't close. Did you put all of this code in your main form's constructor?

Comment: Oh god, don't use recursion!

Comment: @Blorgbeard I can appreciate you reticence.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a "Windows Forms Application" project?

In "Program.cs":

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

Add the button "btnStart" on MainForm.

For this button, add an event handler on click.

In MainForm.cs:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form[] t = new Form[3];

        for (int count = 0; count < t.Length; count++)
        {
            t[count] = new Form();
            t[count].Show();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, your forms will not close after the loop.

Comment: I commented to this effect in the question thread. I'm thinking that the first line inside the for loop ( t[count] = new form() ), because it's initialized inside the loop, may be why it's closing the form at the end of the loop.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Your program doesn't work because it's a console app. You need to call Application.Run, like this answer. Or easier, just make a winforms project instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing all of your code, in fact, the code you are showing doesn't even compile... (`Show` instead of `show`). Without more code, all we can do is guess.

I speculate, but what I think happens is that you close your `MainForm` after you spawn the three forms, exiting the application, and closing the three forms you just created.